# How to change arrow head size of connectors in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I created some diagram in Enterprise Architect and feel that the arrow heads are to big. This is with **Common Relationships** of type **Dependency**.

How can I change the size and/or shape of the arrow heads? There seems to be no such option in the GUI.

Comment: Geert is right. What is the reason for your desire?

Comment: The reason is trivial, I created a diagram, my customer replied like "Yes, nice, thank you, but the arrow heads should be smaller."
Thanks Geert, I understand that it is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Hmm, that would be a bit like doing a code review and complaining that that the chosen font is ugly ;)

Comment: In order to get the arrow head smaller increase the size of the objects ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't, unless you create your own stereotype and write your own shapescript to go along with it.

Remember EA is a **modelling tool**, not a **diagram tool**.

In a modelling language you assign a meaning to a specific shape. Different arrows mean different things, so it seems like a bad idea to allow the user to change the shape of the arrows.